How can it be stabilized for Vuforia Ground Plane Tracking in Native Apps
This is my first post. I would appreciate your advice.
We are using Vuforia in our native app. We recently upgraded from version 9.1.7 to 10.22.5.
We noticed a decrease in the accuracy of ground plane tracking.
Resulting in unstable behavior. After recognizing the floor plane, our 3DCG models are not displayed steadily and appear to be shaking (version 9.1.7 was stable).
According to our team's engineers, there was a change in the tracking methods due to a specification update in Vuforia (it went from two methods to one).
We would appreciate any advice on how to stabilize the behavior.
This has impacted user satisfaction, and we would like to maintain the previous level of accuracy.
Are there any specific settings or configurations that are necessary to achieve this?
We would appreciate any advice on how to stabilize the behavior.

Which device/platform are you using?

Thank you for your comment. I apologize for not providing enough explanation. It's a native app used on iOS and Android smartphones.

Is the issue reproducible on both iOS and Android? For most modern devices Ground-Plane just exposes via the Engine API platform functionality from ARKit/ARCore (see here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/environments/vuforia-fusion). So unless you have a very old device no shaking is expected. I would suggest you go through the troubleshooting steps here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app to nail down the issue.

I would also check how the native API is used in the native samples here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/native-vuforia-engine-sample . There is no ground plane sample code but the way to use Observers should be the same. If you cannot find the issue you should add more info to this question adding some sample code and a video showing your problem

Thank you for your thoughtful advice and comments. I will share your advice with the engineers, have them implement it, and report back to you.
